# Cannot resolve keyword 'available_from_gte' into field. Choices are: available_from, available_till, id, room, room_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_number =  models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000), MinValueValidator(1)],
        primary_key=True
        )

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available_from = models.TimeField()
    available_till = models.TimeField()
```

Here is my views.py

```
    keys = ['room', 'available_from_gte', 'available_till_lte']
    values = [room_obj, available_from, available_till]
    # room_obj contains object of Room model. available_from and available_till contains time in 02:00:00 format.
    parameters = {}
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        if value is not None and value !=[] and value != '':
            parameters[key] = value

    time_slots_list = TimeSlot.objects.filter(**parameters)
```

On running the above code I get the following error.

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'available_from_gte' into field. Choices are: available_from, available_till, id, room, room_id
```

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `available_from__gte`. Notice the double underscore before gte. Accessing into related fields and lookups such as `in` and `gte` are notated with two underscores in field names.

Comment: You are right. I did not notice that. Thanks for help.